# Jsonp not show the entry

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, jsonp

Hi I've tried to parse a json with cross domain but it not work can someone help me?

here the code

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="order">
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

// Caricamento completato documento
$(document).ready(get_order);

function get_order() {
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
    url: 'http://dreamlo.com/lb/539e43736e51b417407de6ce/json/index.json',
    data: {},
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'order',
    jsonpCallback: 'order',
    error: function(xhr, testStatus, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});}function order(data) {
var count = Object.keys(data).length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
    $.each(data.dreamlo.leaderboard.entry[i], function(key, value) {
        if (key == "code_order") {
            $('#order').append(dreamlo.leaderboard.entry.data[i].name);
        }
    });
}};
```

here my json file that is called by the query with the link

```
{
"dreamlo": {
    "leaderboard": {
        "entry": [{
            "name": "oliwier",
                "score": "258021",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/26/2014 12:18:57 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ден",
                "score": "257947",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/24/2014 1:44:26 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "ijijjjjijjijoooijij",
                "score": "233120",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/20/2014 3:08:53 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "اريد+هاذا+المستوا",
                "score": "225081",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/14/2014 11:40:13 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Yafdlkahsjs",
                "score": "221760",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/17/2014 10:18:40 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "prova",
                "score": "210919",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "6/25/2014 3:56:09 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "rodri",
                "score": "158120",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/27/2014 9:23:34 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "щагешп66",
                "score": "152100",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/31/2014 9:06:47 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "jose",
                "score": "149601",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/26/2014 2:51:44 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "jesus",
                "score": "148963",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/13/2014 6:16:04 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "othon",
                "score": "147042",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/10/2014 1:10:38 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "dfvfgs",
                "score": "145439",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/5/2014 2:38:16 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "linda",
                "score": "145163",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/15/2014 2:56:48 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ENZO",
                "score": "143966",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/3/2014 6:45:34 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "jham+04",
                "score": "139788",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/7/2014 8:41:28 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Lukas",
                "score": "138563",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/14/2014 4:39:39 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "calvin+cindy",
                "score": "138320",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/26/2014 9:32:34 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "jojo",
                "score": "138224",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "11/6/2014 6:04:19 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "서현웅",
                "score": "132100",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/9/2014 7:14:59 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "copetti+filippo",
                "score": "131247",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/22/2014 4:29:03 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "David",
                "score": "129419",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/2/2014 1:11:04 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ужвжвжжвжвжв",
                "score": "129361",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/4/2014 5:07:44 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Deandre",
                "score": "127704",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/13/2014 11:32:46 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Mio+Caro",
                "score": "127660",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/26/2014 10:24:51 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ivan",
                "score": "127599",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/5/2014 4:48:02 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "seba",
                "score": "127523",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/1/2014 8:14:20 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "rj",
                "score": "127424",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/25/2014 9:57:19 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "jorge",
                "score": "126827",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/2/2014 8:40:16 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "meka",
                "score": "125285",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/10/2014 10:23:26 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "นัด",
                "score": "125028",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "11/9/2014 12:31:04 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Lucas",
                "score": "121646",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/6/2014 10:13:34 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Josiah",
                "score": "121602",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/24/2014 11:04:06 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "hatty",
                "score": "120109",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/30/2014 7:33:45 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "axeo",
                "score": "118722",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/21/2014 8:51:10 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "LUC",
                "score": "118664",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/4/2014 6:08:56 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "CHON",
                "score": "118647",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/3/2014 3:23:42 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "paul",
                "score": "118624",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/22/2014 8:27:21 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "amari",
                "score": "118623",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/6/2014 1:11:25 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "car",
                "score": "118224",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/13/2014 8:32:07 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "al",
                "score": "117840",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/26/2014 4:29:29 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Uncle+We+We",
                "score": "117564",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/17/2014 6:15:21 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "pisellone",
                "score": "117488",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/27/2014 3:08:06 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "миг",
                "score": "117208",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/26/2014 12:32:16 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "javier",
                "score": "115866",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/2/2014 2:57:01 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "zjnzjzsjjsjdjd",
                "score": "115519",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/13/2014 6:15:53 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "tyreese.+dorrell",
                "score": "114966",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "11/7/2014 5:03:50 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "jordan",
                "score": "114306",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/27/2014 6:14:06 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "eduan",
                "score": "114266",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/5/2014 1:52:14 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "andres",
                "score": "114240",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/29/2014 1:04:22 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "bcg+zg",
                "score": "113780",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/10/2014 11:13:44 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "derek",
                "score": "113607",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/29/2014 1:15:50 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Federico",
                "score": "113325",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/28/2014 4:41:42 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "喔喔哦喲阿公",
                "score": "113002",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/26/2014 11:59:19 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "валера",
                "score": "112784",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/19/2014 7:40:50 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Ben+dragon+stoker",
                "score": "112483",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/6/2014 12:05:42 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "sebbe",
                "score": "111287",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/16/2014 8:18:08 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Valerio",
                "score": "111279",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/3/2014 6:04:21 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Bruno",
                "score": "111163",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/30/2014 8:04:26 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "suryq",
                "score": "110587",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "11/9/2014 9:52:40 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "niko",
                "score": "109961",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/31/2014 1:19:35 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "speed+racer",
                "score": "109404",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/10/2014 2:04:47 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "The+Ultimate1",
                "score": "109340",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/14/2014 5:17:03 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "xander",
                "score": "109267",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/27/2014 12:39:53 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "RER",
                "score": "109246",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/28/2014 11:20:29 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "rua",
                "score": "109222",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/22/2014 4:38:21 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "matteus03",
                "score": "109124",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/21/2014 2:48:02 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "luis",
                "score": "108520",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/28/2014 2:56:15 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Angelisho",
                "score": "108239",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/27/2014 11:19:53 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "NUÑO",
                "score": "107984",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/13/2014 3:54:49 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "dhd",
                "score": "107521",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/8/2014 12:18:45 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Lee",
                "score": "107500",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/25/2014 10:55:24 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "wes",
                "score": "106823",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/30/2014 3:24:22 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ehinar",
                "score": "106705",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/5/2014 9:35:22 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Daniel+Baños",
                "score": "106605",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/11/2014 3:40:20 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "tyler",
                "score": "106486",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/7/2014 7:51:11 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "kryštof",
                "score": "106122",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/15/2014 9:48:46 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Maqbool",
                "score": "106066",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/29/2014 6:59:01 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "mike",
                "score": "105446",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/13/2014 3:13:05 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "nico",
                "score": "105240",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/25/2014 12:36:50 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Asto",
                "score": "105068",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/3/2014 6:42:30 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "dag",
                "score": "104569",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/29/2014 12:39:20 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Simon",
                "score": "104463",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/14/2014 8:21:48 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "hallo",
                "score": "104459",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/6/2014 6:49:58 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "mattia08",
                "score": "103742",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/24/2014 8:49:35 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "ensar",
                "score": "103463",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/11/2014 7:21:42 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Joshua",
                "score": "103343",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/6/2014 5:39:42 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "kmkc",
                "score": "103321",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/11/2014 8:26:14 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "simone",
                "score": "103288",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/16/2014 9:11:37 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "victor",
                "score": "103023",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/5/2014 8:53:07 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Megamind",
                "score": "102939",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/5/2014 9:30:50 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "benne",
                "score": "102381",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/22/2014 4:51:43 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Daniel",
                "score": "102246",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "9/18/2014 1:56:02 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "matt",
                "score": "102222",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/29/2014 11:06:04 AM"
        }, {
            "name": "Taylor",
                "score": "101808",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/21/2014 6:12:57 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "pedrope",
                "score": "101477",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/31/2014 9:10:44 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "Nicolas",
                "score": "101460",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "10/13/2014 6:51:37 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "mecgra",
                "score": "101402",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/2/2014 2:43:13 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "XmkXX",
                "score": "101350",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "7/31/2014 9:08:56 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "VSC",
                "score": "101326",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "8/27/2014 4:07:07 PM"
        }, {
            "name": "GALIH",
                "score": "101247",
                "seconds": "0",
                "text": null,
                "date": "11/3/2014 11:34:44 AM"
        }]
    }
}
```

};

I don't know how can it work please help me!
Thanks a lot!
The return of page is a white page.

Comment: The URL you are hitting doesn't appear to support JSONP.

Comment: What about [Server-Side Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) ?